Setting static IPv4 address , is not contained in subnetmask
I am trying to add a static IP address while installing Ubuntu 20.4 but getting this error:

I want to set the below config:
IP :- 10.11.15.23
Mask :- 255.255.254.0
gateway:- 10.11.15.12


Subnet should be 10.11.14.0/23 ... Subnet does not actually mean "subnet mask" but include it.

A subnet is a network segment defined by a network address and a network mask ... So, a subnet doesn't equal a subnet-mask but rather includes it as part of its definition.
What you did is providing both the mask 255.255.254.0 and its CIDR notation /23 and therefore 255.255.254.0 is treated as an address for the network and 23 is treated as its network mask.
The IP 10.11.15.23 does not belong to the network of 255.255.254.0/23 but rather to the network of 10.11.14.0/23 and this is what you need to use as your subnet.

TL;DR:
Remove the /23 from your subnet. You would use /23 at the end of an IP address to select a subnet, but that isn't needed here.
